# The first result in Google is not my homepage

Tags: seo, google-search

When you type hackisition on Google, it returns the following url as first result:

```
https://www.hackisition.com/en/

// instead of
https://www.hackisition.com/
```

I'd like to replace that link by the real homepage. How can I do that? Is there a way to specifically ask Google to show this homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are getting result as you said , so I suggest to clear cache

[image: Refer Image Below]

Answer (score 2):

I am getting "https://www.hackisition.com/" as first result for "hackisition". I'm not sure why you're getting such result. Try to clear cookies and turn off VPN/Proxy if you're using one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is because of User location.

That mean countries preferred English on search would be able to see /en
and other countries that not prefer English will see the non /en result.

Search your website on 
Google.ae
Google.DK

you'll see https://www.hackisition.com in result not https://www.hackisition.com/en.

But if you search in Google.com, Google.eu you'll see the result https://www.hackisition.com/en

Hope this would be the solution of your problem.